# Python logging error - potentially related to variable scope

Tags: python

I wrote a class and tried to use python logging, but bumped into error.
Basically, I am using code reference at python doc: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html

```
class HDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.logger = None
        test_function()    # This is the problematic call
        self.setup_logger()
        # test_function() should be called here
        ...
    def setup_logger(self):
        # create logger
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('gui')
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # create console handler and set level to debug
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # create formatter
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

        # add formatter to ch
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)

        # add ch to logger
        self.logger.addHandler(ch)

        # 'application' code
        self.logger.debug('debug message')

    def test_function(self):
        self.logger.debug('Test debug')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_dialog = HDialog()
    main_dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The output came out for 'debug message', but for the 'Test debug' it gave me error:
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'debug'

I have a feeling that the self.logger in the setup_logger() is local to that function.
How to fix this in a correct way in python?

Comment: We will need a bit more information in order to debug this, but no self.logger is not local to that method. It is available throughout the instance of HDialog

Comment: This code works. I created an instance of your class and called logger successfully. There definitely is more missing code here.

Comment: There is not way to tell you want's wrong here. How did you call the function? Where is your object stored?

Comment: @tuxtimo  Thanks! Good hints. I checked again: I called test_function() before setup_logger(), that is why the self.logger is not set up yet.  Thank you!

Comment: Okay, so there is more code in the constructor as you've shown us? Because you are calling it in the constructor ..

Comment: Yes, I added the problematic call above.

Comment: I'm confused. You're setting `self.logger` to `None`, then calling a function that tries to use `self.logger.debug`. Shouldn't you move that call to after the `setup_logger` call?